# I need to call fragment from activity

Tags: android

Here, my application have Activity like this

```
public class ticket extends FragmentActivity
```

and my application have fragment like this

```
public class TicketFragment extends Fragment
```

I want to call TicketFragment class from ticket activity. How to call this fragment??? Please Help..

Comment: what do you mean by `call fragment` ?

Comment: post your code first what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code.

In fragment you can access its parent FragmentActivity instance using getActivity().
And since that instance is an activity, so using that you can call another activity simply.

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent((ParentActivity)getActivity(), YourOtherActivity.class);
    (ParentActivity)getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 

or this way it is a small example. it works for me.
s2.java..

public class S2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,OnTouchListener

{ ...

@Override

public void onBackPressed() { .... //I want to call s1.java class here
   S1 fragmentS1 = new S1();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
}

}

s1.java

public class S1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in ticket class-

```
TicketFragment tkt = new TicketFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TicketFragment fragmentB = (TicketFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentBId);
fragmentB.performSomeTask();
```

Here is simplest way of calling a fragment from an activity.

```
Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = new HomeFragment();
if (fragment != null) 
{           
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_lower_right,fragment).commit();            
}

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{

}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer? It'd be good to explain how this works.

Comment: you make a class extends fragment, then get the fragment object and access its public function over there. But if you just wanted to call a fragment from an activity. I have edited my answer that is the simplest way of doing it.